# URLs that contain the text "feed" ask for an app to open with in Chrome for Android 4

Tags: android, google-chrome, url, rss

I'm developing a web app and I have an url that has the word "feedback" in its path. When I tap it, Chrome for Android asks me whether I want to open it with Chrome, with Firefox or with RssDemon (an Rss app I installed).

I played with the url bit by bit until I realized that it's the word "feed" in the URL what triggers that behaviour. It doesn't have to be at the beggining nor at the end. Anything like "feeding animals" or "linefeed code" would have the same effect.

I don't want to have to change my urls to avoid that.

Comment: http://commonsware.com/misc/test.html contains a hyperlink that links to http://commonsware.com/misc/feed.html. Clicking on that hyperlink in Chrome for Android brings up the "feed" page, without prompting me to open the page in Firefox. My guess is that your problem lies more with MIME types.

Comment: It's not the MIME type. I used both wireshark and a TCP tunnel script of my own to sniff at the traffic and two things happen: first, when I tap the link Chrome makes no request, it just shows the choice dialog; second, when requesting the link directly (either by choosing in the dialog, or by typing the URL in the address bar), the server replies with text/html as expected and the page shows correctly.
A bit more of research showed it may be related with an intent-filter installed by the Rss app.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the web app in any way. It's all the fault of RssDemon, the RSS android app. After uninstalling RssDemon, the problem goes away.

It seems that RssDemon set up an URL intent filter so that links clicked on Chrome that had the text feed in them opened with RssDemon. Being a link, it's likely that Android also offers Chrome & Firefox as options to open it.

The bad thing about that is that I can't do anything in my web app to avoid such a behaviour. The good things is that I don't have to :-) . It'll work fine for anyone without an app like RssDemon that installs such an intent filter. And you can't really protect from those, any app could set up a filter for any pattern and it'll be up to the user to decide then.